# Windows Terminal is unable to start in windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-terminal

It's just the terminal won't load at all, I tried everything form resetting to reinstalling the application throw the store but nothing works at all.
I tried to see windows terminal version in the cmd using the command `wt -v` but nothing happens, It's look like the exe file exists but never works.
I also tried to open the application using task manager, and I found out that the process starts for 1 second or 2 then die.

My windows build number is 22621.525

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After posting my problem on windows terminal GitHub issues page, I find out that windows terminal and a lots of other applications like Spotify is unable to work in windows 11 pro N, where windows is missing an important Optional Feature called Media Feature Pack.

After installing it and restarting my computer everything started to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Current Production Windows 11 Pro build (and Home I think) is 22000.1042.

**(A)** First try DISM / SFC

```
(1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.
```

**(B)** If the above does not work and your Windows 11 is properly activated, did you upgrade from Windows 10 or do a fresh install.

You may need to do a Windows 11 Repair Install

Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

> Windows 10/11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. This will launch the Repair.  Proceed normally
> answering the prompts. The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

A repair install will update Windows and Drivers, is painless to do, and is likely worthwhile to do,